# Android ksoap2 WCF wsHttpBinding

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, wshttpbinding

I am trying to connect my android application to WCF web service (IIS 6),with 
basicHttpBinding everything works OK, but i want it to be more secure so i set the
WCF binding to wsHttpBinding, i understed this is a littele bit tricky on ksoap2,
i am getting an error:

> Code: s:Sender, Reason: The message could not be processed.
>    This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/HelloWorld'
>    is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or
>    because there is a mismatch between bindings. 
>   The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity.
>    To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout
>    on the service endpoint's binding.

Here is my code (android)

```
Element e = new Element();
    e.setName("To");
    e.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
    e.addChild(Node.TEXT,
            URL);


    Element e1 = new Element();
    e1.setName("Action");
    e1.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
    e1.addChild(Node.TEXT,
            "http://tempuri.org/IService1/HelloWorld");




    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    //envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    //envelope.headerOut =new Element[] { e, e1 };
    envelope.headerOut = buildHeader(URL, SOAP_ACTION);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request); // prepare request

    try {
        // androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        String resultData=result.getProperty(0).toString();
        //Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        //SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        //String resultData = result.toString();

        //msg = resultData;

    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        msg = ex.getMessage();
    }
```

i all so try:

```
private static Element[] buildHeader(String url, String soapAction) {

    String HTTP_ADDRESSING_ANONYMOUS = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous";
    String HTTP_ADDRESSING = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
    String ACTION = "Action";
    String TO = "To";
    String ADDRESS = "Address";
    String REPLY_TO = "ReplyTo";
    String MUST_UNDERSTAND = "mustUnderstand";

    List<Element> headers = new ArrayList<Element>();
    Element elementAction = new Element().createElement(HTTP_ADDRESSING, ACTION);
    elementAction.addChild(Node.TEXT, soapAction);
    elementAction.setAttribute(HTTP_ADDRESSING, MUST_UNDERSTAND, "1");
    headers.add(elementAction);

    Element elementTo = new Element().createElement(HTTP_ADDRESSING, TO);
    elementTo.addChild(Node.TEXT, url);////////////////////////////
    elementTo.setAttribute(HTTP_ADDRESSING, MUST_UNDERSTAND, "1");
    headers.add(elementTo);

    Element elementReplyto = new Element().createElement(HTTP_ADDRESSING, REPLY_TO);
    Element address = new Element().createElement(HTTP_ADDRESSING, ADDRESS);
    elementReplyto.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, address);
    address.addChild(Node.TEXT, HTTP_ADDRESSING_ANONYMOUS);
    elementReplyto.setAttribute(HTTP_ADDRESSING, MUST_UNDERSTAND, "1");
    headers.add(elementReplyto);

    int size = headers.size();
    Element[] array = new Element[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = headers.get(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

can someone Help

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No. only setting the WCF to httpbasicbinding,witch mean it is like a regular soap protocol, so understanding that i don't gain any security with WCF basic binding, i am using .asmx web service